# how to check if file trashed or not google drive api

Tags: php, api, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

i have a problem, im using this [client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client) form my app to google drive api.

but the problem is i cant check if the files is `trashed` or not.

here what i try

```
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setScopes(\Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setAuthConfig(app_path().'/Credentials/gDrive.json');

$service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);
$folder = $service->files->get("fileid");
```

this always return trashed as null, what ever it trashed or not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to check whether whether the file is put in "Trash" using googleapis for php.
- You have already been able to get the file metadata using Drive API.
- You are using Drive API v3.

#### Modification point:

- When Drive API v3 is used, all file metadata is not returned by the method of "Files: get". I think that the reason of your issue is this. So in this case, it is required to use `fields`. In your case, if you want to check only `trashed`, you can use `trashed` as the fields.

When this is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
$folder = $service->files->get("fileid");
```

To:

```
$folder = $service->files->get("fileid", array("fields" => "trashed"));
$trashed = $folder['trashed'] ? "true" : "false";
echo $trashed;
```

- When the file of `fileid` is put in "Trash", `$trashed` is `true`.
- When the file of `fileid` is NOT put in "Trash", `$trashed` is `false`.

#### Note:

- For example, you want to all file metadata, you can use `"fields" => "*"` instead of `"fields" => "trashed"`.

#### Reference:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)

Comment: i see, thanks, by the way you miss `s` on `field` it should be `fields => ""`

Comment: @Jazuly Thank you for replying and your support. I had miscopied when I wrote the answer. I apologize for this. I could notice it from your replying and update my answer. Thank you, too.